# How not to show user text (password) entry into textbox (like su command does)

Tags: c, gtk

I have a `GtkEntry`, in which the user must provide the password.

I did

```
gtk_entry_set_visibility(GTK_ENTRY(password_entry), FALSE);
```

to use another symbol instead of real password in pure text, but I want the `GtkEtry` not to show the text while the user is typing the passord, like the su program does.

How can I do this?

Comment: btw., why do you say "GtkBox"? Didn't you mean to say "GtkEntry"?

Comment: @Ancurio: My mistake. I'II edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [docs](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/2.24/GtkEntry.html#gtk-entry-set-visibility), right below `gtk_entry_set_visibility`, there is **gtk_entry_set_invisible_char**, which has following notes:

> [...] If you set the invisible char to 0, then the user will get no feedback
>   at all; there will be no text on the screen as they type.

Comment: Note that you should store the password in a protected memory buffer too. Not just omit displaying it. I don't know if Gtk offers such thing.

Comment: @NikosChantziaras That's interesting. How does one use "protected memory"? I always thought the program memory way already protected by the OS from external reading. Do you mean protecting it from getting swapped to disk?

Comment: "Protected" means being secure from leaking it after you're done with it. If the memory where you stored the password is deallocated, the contents of that memory aren't cleared. The password is still there.

Comment: (I messed up with this tiny comments-editor). Swapping a password to disk is also a bad thing. When it comes to defensive programming, I always have that famous quote in my mind: just because you're paranoid doesn't mean they're not out to get you :-) The following article pretty much sums it up: [link](http://www.cgisecurity.com/lib/protecting-sensitive-data.html)

Comment: @NikosChantziaras ah, that's true, and it never occurred to me.. although it would be one hell of work to swim through all RAM to find a 10 char password =P

Comment: @NikosChantziaras: I will check out this articl thanks very much too :)

Comment: You can use `libgnome-keyring` or `libsecret` for protected memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't find something better you can do this:

Connect a signal to the gtk_entry (or any gtk_editable) on "insert_text", get the char typed, store it and finally use g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(G_OBJECT(editable), "insert_text"); to hide the char

An example, this code discards non digit chars:

```
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(form->field[i].control), "insert_text", G_CALLBACK(insert_text_handler), GINT_TO_POINTER(form->field[i].type_of));

void insert_text_handler(GtkEditable *editable, const gchar *text, gint length, gint *position, gpointer data)
{
    gint i;

    switch(GPOINTER_TO_INT(data)) {
        case TYPE_DIGIT:
            for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                if (!isdigit(text[i])) {
                    g_signal_stop_emission_by_name(G_OBJECT(editable), "insert_text");
                    return;
                }

...
```